# Is it possible to change the console font size in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, font-size, intellij-15

Is it possible to change the console font size in IntelliJ IDEA?

I changed the actual text size under *Settings > Editor > Font*, but "console/terminal" font is too small.

I'm using Community Edition 15

Answer (score 115, accepted):

### Works on every Intellij Version

Press `Ctrl+Shift+a` and search for `console font`:

[image]

Select `Console Font` and the right settings menu will be opened.

### Intellij Version < 2018

Open `Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Console Font`

You can change font size and colors there but you have to save the Scheme into a custom scheme before you can change the values.

[image]

I am using the ultimate edition. If you don't see that settings it's probably because of the community edition you are using.

### Intellij Version >= 2018

Open `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Font`

[image]

Comment: I had to *make a copy* of my current scheme to be able to change this.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 Ultimate is the same.

Comment: In Version 2018.2.4 the option is found here: Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Font -> Use console font instead of default. I like the Line Spacing, set to 0.6. This makes it quite dense!