# how to enlarge the console text in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, ide

I'm using intellij IDEA

But the font in my console is very small.

How can I make this font larger?

I managed to change size font of the code itself, but not the console or any lower bar window.

[image]

Comment: This question is answered previously check this stack-overflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829103/is-it-possible-to-change-the-console-font-size-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Colors & Fonts** -> **Console Font**

Refer [this](https://dzone.com/articles/change-font-terminal-tool) for more.